# How to enable/disable "Profile GPU rendering" on code?

Tags: android

I'm working to developing a debug tools, I want to enable/disable some debug options on developer options by code, such as Profile GPU rendering/ USB Debugging/ show screen updates etc.

My question is how to modify this options? I'm tried to reflecting `android.os.SystemProperties` and invoking 'set' method but get an exception said no permission to modify system props, and `Runtim.exec("setprops $key &value")` return same exception.

So, any other way's to do it? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On a regular device, with a regular app, you can't.

You need a rooted device, with an app in /system/app, then you can.